# Power BI - Creating a calculated table

Tags: powerbi

I am creating a dashboard in Power BI.  I have to report the executions of a process in a daily basis.  When selecting one of these days, I want to create another calculated table based on the day selected (providing concrete information about the number of executions and hours) as it follows:

```
TABLE_B = FILTER(TABLE_A; TABLE_A[EXEC_DATE] = [dateSelected])
```

When [dateSelected] is previously calculated from the selected day as it follows:

```
dateSelected = FORMAT(FIRSTDATE(TABLE_A[EXEC_DATE]);"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

I tried a lot of alternatives as, for example, create individualy the year, month and day to later compare. I used the format in both sides of the comparation, but none of them works for me.  The most of the cases it returns me the whole source table without any kind of filters.  In other cases, it doesn't return anything.  But, when I put a concrete day ...

```
TABLE_B = FILTER(TABLE_A; TABLE_A[EXEC_DATE] = "20/02/2019")
```

... it makes the filter correctly generating the table as I want.

Does someone know how to implement the functionality I am searching for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is "dateSelected" selected?

Comment: dateSelected is the one I click in the bar plot to focus on one day.  I want to use this value to "zoom" later on the ocurrences on that day.  Thanks

Comment: In that case, your approach won't work (at all). Calculated tables and columns can not respond to user selections - they are calculated only once, when you build them. You will need to use measures instead. The answer you accepted can not address the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there Juan. You simply need to use `dateSelected` as a varialbe inside of your DAX query:

```
TABLE_B = 
    var dateSelected = FIRSTDATE(TABLE_A[EXEC_DATE])
return
    FILTER(TABLE_A, TABLE_A[EXEC_DATE] = dateSelected)
```

Note that all my dates are formatted as Date so I didn't need to use a `FORMAT` function.

Here's the final result:

[image]

I admit that this behavior can be quite confusing! Here is a useful link that will help you understand Power BI's **context**:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Filtering-table-by-measures/td-p/131361

Let's treat *option 1* as `FILTER(TABLE_A; TABLE_A[EXEC_DATE] = "20/02/2019")` and *option 2* as `FILTER(TABLE_A; TABLE_A[EXEC_DATE] = [dateSelected])`. Quote from the post:

> In *option 1*, in the filter function, you are iterating
>   over each row of your 'Table' (row context). In *option 2*, because you
>   are using a measure as part of the filter condition, this row context
>   is transformed into an equivalent filter context (context transition).
>
> Using variables (...) is very convenient when you want to filter
>   a column based on the value of a measure but you don't want context
>   transition to apply.

Comment: You're most welcome Juan :-) it was also a good refresher for me.

Comment: Thanks again.  But now I checked, I still have the problem.  This formula gives me the first date in the TABLE_A.  What I want is the day I selected in the bar plot created with such a dataset.

Almost, in this first step I learnt how to pass the variable to the second dataset. But the variable to pass is the other. 

Sorry, I have just checked.  

Thanks

Comment: Hi Juan, would it help if you posted a screenshot of your current report or ask a new question? Did you maybe try playing around with [Edit Interactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-reports-visual-interactions) option? I think you want to press a bar with a specific date (e.g. 18 March 2020) and have a table (table B) present the data just for that specific selection, while table A (original table) would stay unaffected. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @JustynaMK - I think he is trying to filter calculated table (data model table, not visual) by user selections. This is simply impossible.

Comment: Fair point @RADO, thank you. I'll wait for further clarification then.

Comment: Thanks RADO and JustynaMK.  Now I know this is impossible, I will check in another way how to do it.

Thanks again!